# xor encryption help need

Tags: .net, iphone, android, blackberry

I would like to encrypt data using XOR on Android, iPhone, and BlackBerry.  I need to decrypt the data in a .net webservice.

Is XOR encryption available on BlackBerry and iPhone?

Comment: Why would you ever prefer using a XOR cipher?

Comment: "i would prefer to encrypt data using XOR"? Why? XOR is about the simplest possible way to "encrypt" data - it is so simple that it's almost wrong to call it "encryption".

Comment: @Karl: that all depends on the key, doesn’t it?

Comment: Well it is rather obfuscation, but sometime that a valid practice in cases where the data is not really sensible. AFAIK the XOR operator is available on all languages I know of. OP might want to look up the one liner algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On BlackBerry, which uses j2me, though the language operators are the same as java SE, [there is an "exclusive OR"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) operator.

The objective-C language, which is what iPhone uses, [also has an exclusive OR operator](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/objectivec-operators.html).